# Questions about the profession of Philosophy

Tags: discussion

The guidelines for questions in the Philosophy Stack Exchange clearly state that the questions must be *directly* to do with Philosophy.
On one interpretation, this states that the questions must be philosophical. But is the Philosophy Stack Exchange also a place for posting questions concerning the Profession of Philosophy? Such a question would not be, strictly speaking, philosophical, but would still be, in some sense, *about philosophy*.

[EDIT]: I poorly expressed myself above. The distinction intended is one about the ideas discussed. A question, "what did Locke think of x", is a question about philosophical ideas, whilst a question, "what percentage of an academic career in philosophy is typically spent on research leave", does not concern philosophical ideas.

Comment: The Academy might be better for strictly academic-career focused sorts of things (wider user base than just teachers and students of philosophy)

Comment: @JosephWeissman - I appreciate it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @JosephWeissman I suppose you mean [academia.se]? That would be a good idea. We also have a [tag:history-of-philosophy] tag.

Comment: A question about the professional practice of philosophy is a question *about* philosophy. A philosophical question is not necessarily a question about philosophy. I think you have the issue backwards, as in, yes this site is for questions about philosophy and philosophical questions. "What did Locke think of x" is not a philosophical question, it's a question *about* philosophy, and that's I think a very obvious question that exists within the purview of this site.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I suppose the distinction intended is one about the ideas discussed. A question "what did Locke think of x" is a question about philosophical ideas, whilst a question "what percentage of an academic career in philosophy is typically spent on research leave" does not concern philosophical ideas.

Comment: @BeingOfNothingness But it's still a question about philosophy, meaning the field of study of whatever it is that philosophy studies, so I don't see how there can be an objection to that kind of question. What you're saying is that questions have to do with philosophical things (ideas, concepts, arguments), but that's not what the rules of the site say. The rules say the questions have to do with philosophy.

Comment: @Not_Here Fantastic, this is the response I wanted to hear.